# When I change name and username on Gmail, will my name change in previous conversations?

Tags: gmail, google-account, account-management

I have recently changed my username and account name on my Gmail account.
It works perfectly (for now) but I noticed when I entered in some of my past email conversations that it still shows up my old account name/username.

Is there a way to fix this, to somehow update my Gmail account so that my new username/account name shows in my past email conversations?

Answer (score -1):

When you change your profile name in your Google account, your previous name will remain in previous conversations. This behaviour can't be fixed anyhow at this moment.

[image: 0]